# My 19.04 Ubuntu terminal keep shrinking in size

Tags: gnome-terminal, 19.04

I upgraded to 19.04. I notice that *gnome-terminal* opens with a height of 24 rows and a width of 80 characters. But when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> to zoom in and again <kbd>F11</kbd> to shrink back, it changes to 23x79. If I repeat again <kbd>F11</kbd> and back, it becomes 22x78. Anyone else experiencing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. The *gnome-terminal* still shrinking its size when I maximize and restore the window. This does not happen in **WAYLAND** though.

I have decided that this is a call to change my habit of using Ubuntu terminals. So I will maximum the window using <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>, keep it that way, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>to open more tabs. This way, the screen size is always maximized and maintain the same size. If needed, I can minimize it by <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, and call it back via <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I was using Thinkpad T460 with 1366x768 resolution. I was having problem with gnome-terminal size shrinking when I press F11 to toggle the size. Today I changed the laptop, still T460, but has 1900x1080 resolution. It is *still* having the same problem.

The video driver is:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)`

Could be this the problem?